# Boolean Pythagorean Triples Problem

Tags: reference-request, coloring, ramsey-theory

A few years ago, the [Boolean Pythagorean Triples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_Pythagorean_triples_problem) problem was solved and shown to be impossible for $n\ge 7825$. Is there a way to show that the number $n$ is bounded just with Ramsey theory, and if so, could anyone point me to the proper reference? All the articles I seem to find deal with SAT solvers as opposed to the Ramsey theory behind the problem.

Comment: edited! thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No such proof is currently known.

As a toy example, it is easy to show that it's impossible to color the integers with three colors such that every Pythagorean triple includes all three colors: take the four triples $$(319, 360, 481), (31, 480, 481), (481, 600, 769), (360, 480, 600)$$ which are impossible to color in this way. (Say the colors are red, blue, and green, and $481$ is red. Then the first three triples ensure that none of $360$, $480$, or $600$ can be red; therefore $(360, 480, 600)$ is colored only using blue and green.)

There was some work done even prior to 2016 about trying to find a more complicated, but still small configuration like this one for the two-color problem. For example, the [Fano plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fano_plane) is impossible to two-color without getting a monochromatic line, so if we could find a Fano plane in the Pythagorean triples hypergraph, we'd obtain a short proof. However, Cooper and Poirel [proved in 2008](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/7242/5e29b5572cb716a7a09ef171e47f05398794.pdf) that the Fano plane is not realizable via Pythagorean triples, and in fact, neither is any Steiner triple system.

In principle, it's still possible that some set of only a few (likely very large) triples can be found that's not two-colorable, and this would give a human-readable proof of the result. However, searching for other small configurations among the Pythagorean triples is hard, and very similar to still-open problems; for example, the [perfect cuboid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_brick#Perfect_cuboid) problem.

Comment: IMHO the last of the four triples should read $(\mathbf{360}, 480, 600)\,$, just as the triple in the textline below.
If you do not mind, then I'd go to edit & align it.

Comment: @Hanno Of course it should - thank you for pointing out the error!